# chef-solo explained

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

Can somebody help me out understanding chef-solo. Still I didnt understood the part whether I have to run chef-solo on my machine to run provision a machine or I need to first provision a machine and install solo on the new machine that I provisioned. I need to understand end to end flow. Please help me better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed explanation on how to use Chef-Solo in AWS environment in [Integrating AWS CloudFormation With Opscode Chef.pdf](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithOpscodeChef.pdf)

> Chef Solo can be used to deploy Chef cookbooks and roles without a
>   dependency on a Chef Server.  Chef Solo can be installed via a Ruby
>   Gem package; however, it requires a number of other  dependent
>   packages to be installed. By using resource metadata and the AWS
>   CloudFormation  helpers, you can deploy Chef Solo on a base AMI via
>   Cloud-init.

You can either use the cloud formation that is provided in the PDF above, or you can create the files and run the script (that are embedded in this template) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use chef-solo with vagrant for testing how a target linux distro will behave on your local machine; however, your question is more about an end to end with AWS - so here we go.

end to end you need on the target machine the following dependencies at least:

ruby, the gem chef, ssh, git or some other way of getting your code to the vm.

You ssh into the machine, you get the recipes you want to use on the target machine, you run chef-solo with some parameters that specify at a minimum some attributes, the location of your cookbooks, and a run list that contains some recipes or roles to apply to the target machine.  Below is an example for getting the apt recipe and mongo recipes (https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt and https://github.com/edelight/chef-mongodb) ... I cloned those into the /opt/devops location on the target machine.

```
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json
```

solo.rb contents

```
file_cache_path "/opt/devops/log"
cookbook_path "/opt/devops/cookbooks"
```

node.json contents

```
{ 
"node": {
"vm_ip": [ "192.168.33.10" ],
"myProject": {
  "git_revision":"bzrDevel",
}
},
"run_list": ["recipe[apt]","recipe[mongodb]" ]
}
```